# responsive-components機能を実装したい。

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, css, node.js

#### やりたいこと

Railsで下記を実装したいのです。
画面分割かつ可変なウェブコンポーネントです。
https://philipwalton.github.io/responsive-components/

#### 困ってること

`Rails`に移行する方法がイメージできないこと。

#### 現状

`$ git clone`
`$ npm start`
`localhostでdemo実行`

までできたのですが、このデモでは`node.js`を使っている？関係で、`Rails`で同じような機能を実装する方法がイメージできません。(`javascript`は文法程度で、`node.js`は触ったことありません。)
今までは`slim`と`bootstrap4`等のテンプレートエンジンを利用してきたのですが、`bootstrap4`でも上記と同じような機能の実装はできなさそうなのが現状です。

上記を`Railsアプリ`内で実装する流れ？をご教授いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 関係ありそうな質問　https://teratail.com/questions/119136

Comment: npmアップデートがお答えになっていて、惜しいです。